# Clustering geo-data for heatmap

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, geocoding, cluster-analysis, heatmap

I have a list of tweets with their geo locations.
They are going to be displayed in a heatmap image transparently placed over Google Map.
The trick is to find groups of locations residing next to each other and display
them as a single heatmap circle/figure of a certain heat/color, based on cluster size.

Is there some library ready to grouping locations in a map into clusters?
Or I better should decide my clusterization params and build a custom algorithm?

Comment: Can you accept an answer? There's a few here that get at what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a 'library ready to grouping locations in a map into clusters', maybe it is, maybe it isn't. Anyways, I don't recommend you to build your custom clustering algorithm since there are a lot of libraries already implemented for this.

@recursive sent you a link with a php code for k-means (one clustering algorithm). There is also a huge Java library with other techniques ([Java-ML](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/)) including k-means too, hierarchical clustering, k-means++ (to select the centroids), etc.

Finally I'd like to tell you that clustering is a non-supervised algorithm, which means that effectively, it will give you a set of clusters with data inside them, but at a first glance **you don't know how the algorithm clustered your data**. I mean, it may be clustered by locations as you want, but it can be clustered also by another characteristic you don't need so it's all about playing with the parameters of the algorithm and *tune* your solutions.

I'm interested in the final solution you could find to this problem :) Maybe you can share it in a comment when you end this project!

Answer (score 2):

[K means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) is a technique often used for such problems

The basic idea is this:

> Given an initial set of k means m<sub>1</sub>,…,m<sub>k</sub>, the
>   algorithm proceeds by alternating between two steps:
>
> 1. Assignment step: Assign each observation to the cluster with the closest mean
> 2. Update step: Calculate the new means to be the centroid of the observations in the cluster.

[Here](http://code.blip.pt/2009/04/06/k-means-clustering-in-php/) is some sample code for php.

Answer (score 1):

[heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) is an HTML5 library for rendering heatmaps, and has a sample for doing it on top of the Google Maps API. It's pretty robust, but only works in browsers that support canvas:

> The heatmap.js library is currently supported in Firefox 3.6+, Chrome
>   10, Safari 5, Opera 11 and IE 9+.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my php class hilbert curve at phpclasses.org. It's a monster curve and reduces 2d complexity to 1d complexity. I use a quadkey to address a coordinate and it has 21 zoom levels like Google maps.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a clustering problem. Head maps don't work by creating clusters. Instead they convolute the data with a gaussian kernel.  If you're not familiar with image processing, think of it as using a normal or gaussian "stamp" and stamping it over each point. Since the overlays of the stamp will add up on top of each other, areas of high density will have higher values.

Answer (score 0):

One simple alternative for heatmaps is to just round the lat/long to some decimals and group by that.

See [this explanation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674) about lat/long decimal accuracy.

- 1 decimal - 11km
- 2 decimals - 1.1km
- 3 decimals - 110m

etc.

For a low zoom level heatmap with lots of data, rounding  to 1 or 2 decimals and grouping the results by that should do the trick.